# Why does mysql treat all the derivations of a character the same?

Tags: mysql, unicode

Suppose a table with a field encoded as unicode_ci with the record *'Grün'* in it.

If I do the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM `knows_names` WHERE `name`='Grun'
```

It will output my record *(even if it has a diaeresis on the U)*.

**Question:**

Why does it behave that way? Once I read Unicode treats each letter as a single entity, and then if you put an accent or diaeresis on it it is saved apart in some way, as an addon to it. Please correct me if I am saying something stupid. And maybe Mysql is only comparing the PURE letter, forgetting about fancy addons. But in that way, it's crazy, cause **ç** is not **c**, and maybe it would be interesting not to get all the variations, but the one we are looking for. All I want to know is what is happening, and why.

Comment: Depends on the collation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27077

Comment: Thanks, where can I find out WHY it happens. Nice example :D